# Only one laptop fan running

Tags: debian

I just Installed debian 11 and i8kutils in dell g5 5505 SE (ryzen 5 , Radeon 5600m GPU) , I tested the fans with **i8kctl fan 2 2** command, and noticed only one (right GPU fan is running) and other fan is not running, what should I do to make it work?

Comment: it's possible that the fan doesn't *need* to spin up unless a certain temperature is met? i'd check the CPU temps and see how they look

Comment: @brxken Even in windows,  it uses Alienware control center to control the fan, without Alienware control center the fans won't work